# Упорядочить строки матрицы по убыванию максимальных элементов. c++

Tags: c++, массивы, пузырьковая-сортировка

Через векторы преподаватель не принял, сказал сделать через пузырьковый метод. Надо отсортировать массив так, чтобы выводилось:

исх.масс:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |

| 4 | 5 | 6 |

| 7 | 8 | 9 |

отс. масс:

| 7 | 8 | 9 |

| 4 | 5 | 6 |

| 1 | 2 | 3 |

На данный момент код сортирует элементы в строке, не знаю что надо поменять.

````
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime> 

using namespace std;

int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU"); 
int N, M, b[10], r, j, i, t; 

cout << "n= ";
cin >> N;
cout << "m= ";
cin >> M;

int** matrix = new int* [N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    matrix[i] = new int[M];

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        cout << "Введите M[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
        cin >> matrix[i][j];
    }
}

cout << "Исходная матрица:" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        cout.width(5);
        cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}

for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
{
    b[j] = matrix[0][j];
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
        if (matrix[i][j] < b[j])
            b[j] = matrix[i][j];
}
for (j = 0; j < M - 1; j++)
    for (i = j + 1; i < N; i++)
        if (b[j] < b[i])
        {
            t = b[j];
            b[j] = b[i];
            b[i] = t;
            for (r = 0; r < N; r++)
            {
                t = matrix[r][j];
                matrix[r][j] = matrix[r][i];
                matrix[r][i] = t;
            }
        }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Матрица после сортировки строк:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            cout.width(5);
            cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: Немного не к конкретному вопросу, но вас не смущает `for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
{ .... for (i = 1; i < N; i++) .... matrix[i][j]`, при том, что размеры матрицы NxM?

Comment: В чём загвоздка - вы не знаете, как найти максимум в строке?

Comment: я просто не до  конца понимаю. Сначала находиться максимум в одной строке, потом в другой. А как менять строки?